# Fill up screen with browser?

Tags: c#

I'm making a program that will fill up the user's screen programatically, I was thinking I would grab their screen dimensions and just set the size to that, here's the code I'm using:

```
public Rectangle GetScreen()
{
        return Screen.FromControl(this).Bounds;
}

this.wb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.wb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(GetScreen());
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm getting the error 'Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Rectangle' to 'System.Drawing.Point'.

Comment: You can always do this.wb.Size = GetScreen().Size;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error you gave specifies, you are using incorrect arguments for the `System.Drawing.Size` constructor — [System.Drawing.Size Constructor (Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5e470e7f(v=vs.110).aspx) or [System.Drawing.Size Constructor (Point)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/226tw7a0(v=vs.110).aspx).

Use the following code instead:

```
Rectangle screen = GetScreen();
this.wb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(screen.Width, screen.Height);
```

As @dharshanajagoda mentioned in a comment, you can also just do

```
this.wb.Size = GetScreen().Size;
```